# How can i publish data/events from all goroutines to a webservice?

Tags: web-services, go, channel, goroutine

My Project is a TCP server (not http) and works something like this

```
main() {

for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    go handleClient(conn, &Client{})
}
```

I usually have hundreds of clients connecting at the same time

inside handleconnection, my "events" look something like this

```
IP
1.2.3.4 client connect
1.2.3.4 client send command XYZ
1.2.3.4 client send data
server send data to 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4 client send command XYZ
[repeated N times]
```

For each of these events, i want to create a "real time view" of events accross my goroutines and all the clients. Basically, you could say its a status for each connecting client

something that would looke like

```
client IP   status          time    total KB    
1.2.3.4     connect         1       0
5.6.7.8     send data       14      22
10.10.10.10 recieving data  22      11
```

I have all the information i need in each connections (handleconn) but i have no idea how to make this available for a webservice.

**Problem**: How do i make all of these event status msg availble for a function, or another goroutine or something which can collect everything from all goroutines and publish it?

Do i need to use channels for this? or another go routine which is launched only one time and can recieve data using channels

Or a completely other approach to collect and publish the data?

*disclaimer: Im very new to programming and golang. Just an old dude trying to learn*

Answer (score 4):

There is a package in the Go library that is designed for this use, `expvar`. According to the docs, it already does all the wrapping as web service for you:

http://golang.org/pkg/expvar/

Comment: looks right, however, very limited in features. for example, you can Add(d) to your counter, but not subtract from the same counter. i found a way around it.. but seems somehow limited, or am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Also seem to lack some way to delete or expire a variable or map. for example, i can Init() the map but it will keep the keys, just NIL the values. again, maybe something here im missing? Just seem to me like, if i add more and more, mem usage will keep increasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a type `Supervisor` which will keep a registry of all your `Connection`.

Each `Connection` will have some properties such as `ClientIP`, `Status`, `Time` and `TotalKB`.

When there is a new connection, instantiate a new `Connection`, add it to the supervisor's registry and spawn a Go routine. The go routine will update its own informations depending on what's going on.

From the Supervisor you have access to all the Connections, and you can therefore display what you want on the terminal or web. It's up to you.

To keep the registry up-to-date, you can use [Tomb](https://gopkg.in/tomb.v2), which is really useful when you have to track go routines.

I hope it will help